# unable to setup proxy system wide in kubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, virtualbox, kubuntu, proxy

i am running kubuntu 18.04 in virtualbox and currently working in a proxy environment. when i am trying to setup the proxy through
       **system settings ->network settings -> proxy** .

then i see no changes and unable to browse. no system wide changes are observed ,ie proxy on system environment is not afftected after this . but as i  am running 
        **export_proxy http_proxy=http://'proxy:port'**
env variable is changes and able to use the internet connectivity.

please provide solution for this , to setup proxy system wide through setting ,not by export_proxy ( i don't want to unset the proxy each time as i shift to non-proxy environment.)

Comment: Are you using Firefox ? It has its own proxy settings and ignore system-wide settings (as of writing).

Comment: @JohnChristopher yes I was using Firefox, but this issue also exists for chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you precise the string format you use to setup proxy system wide
trough system settings -> network settings -> proxy

http://proxy_host:port
or 
proxy_host:port

i open a bug against firefox and ask a similar question to ubuntu:

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1582359
- https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-docs/+question/684083

i suppose (it works for me) if you type
http://proxy_host:port
it works for firefox
(but not for evolution or pidgin)

IMHO it's wrong to say : FF has its own proxy settings and ignore system-wide settings
and in my case : chrome uses proxy settings and i can browse with both values :
http://proxy_host:port or proxy_host:port

Comment: thanks for solution, right now i have no access to the system to check this one, but yes your solution is right and one can set the proxy this way also.